# GetDlgItem() returns invalid handle in vc++ 2019 for a project build on 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, visual-studio-2015, mfc

I am recently converting a Visual Studio 8.0 project to Visual Studio 2019 and I'm encountering an issue whenever calling `GetDlgItem` on certain items. The following code is failing.

```
PPOtypeComboHndl[0] = GetDlgItem(Hndl, IDC_PPO_TYPE1);
assert(PPOtypeComboHndl[0] != NULL);
LOG_INFO() << "PPOtypeComboHndl Hndl value is " << PPOtypeComboHndl[0];
```

The value logged in 000000 which seems incorrect.

I see this code in my resource file for the form that's calling the above code.

```
COMBOBOX        IDC_PPO_TYPE1,140,247,54,13,CBS_DROPDOWN | CBS_SORT | WS_VSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP
```

Call to `GetDlgItem()` the control item handel is invalid I believe. This is not an issue in the 8.0 version of the project. `IDC_PPO_TYPE1` seems to be a valid resource on this form. This seems to be  issues while converting the project from 8.0 to 2019.

Comment: Without a [mcve], we can't evaluate what is wrong with your setup. We can't see what your resource looks like, or what is defined in it. We can't see what your code looks like that is creating the dialog, or trying to access the ComboBox. If I had to guess, either `IDC_PPO_TYPE1` is not defined correctly, or `Hndl` is not pointing at the dialog you are expecting.

Comment: I don't know which function you are calling from where. MFC uses `CWnd* control = GetDlgItem(IDC_PPO_TYPE1);` you can call this for example after `CDialog::OnInitDialog`. And then there is Windows API `HWND hwnd_control = ::GetDlgItem(m_hWnd, IDC_PPO_TYPE1)` where `m_hWnd` is the handle of the parent window, you have to make sure the parent window is created, the handle can be tested using `::IsWindow(m_hWnd)`

Comment: Thanks - I do get the events to my event handler so I believe that Hndl value is correct. But I am unable to set default values in control UI items

Comment: Most likely you are using the wrong `Hndl` or it's at the wrong time. Use `::IsWindow(Hndl)` and `::GetWindowText(Hndl, title, 100);` to check it's the right dialog box. You can also use Spy++ from Visual Studio's tool menu, to check the window handle against `Hndl`

Comment: Call `GetLastError()` immediately after the `GetDlgItem()` call. `GetDlgItem()` is a system call (not MFC) and should not fail. Either the dialog handle or the control ID is wrong. Log them both, at the same point in your code as the `GetDlgItem()` call and compare the logged values to the ones shown in the `SpyXX` utility (select Spy->Find Window, drag the target to the dialog window and examine its properties - handle and children). You have to find out where they got the wrong values.

Comment: When are you actually calling your code? We have no **context**.

Comment: Thanks a lot @roccobaroccoSC  ​-  EnumChildWindow API did the trick for me - thanks a ton for your valid input

Answer (score 0):

It seems you already had a hunch about the solution:

> the control item handel is invalid I believe

That's probably your problem.

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getdlgitem):

> As long as the hDlg parameter specifies a parent window and the child
> window has a unique identifier (as specified by the hMenu parameter in
> the CreateWindow or CreateWindowEx function that created the child
> window), GetDlgItem returns a valid handle to the child window.

You must make sure that `hDlg` is a valid handle to the dialog and also, check in the header file if `IDC_PPO_TYPE1` is unique. Maybe you added something and the identifiers clashed?

Comment: Thanks - yes from logs I can see that hDlg used in GetDlgItem is valid. Alo the ID of the item is unique

Comment: Is there any other way to get the handle if conreol other than GetDlgItem - any Win APIs are there?

Comment: If I recall correctly, theoretically you could loop through the items via [EnumChildWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumchildwindows) because buttons and other controls are implemented as windows. I don't know if this works for all dialog items though. I may be mistaken on that, it's been a while. But GetDlgItem is the proper function to do what you want, in my opinion you are probably using it incorrectly - either at the wrong time, or with an incorrect parameter.

Comment: My suggestion is to create a minimal working example that we could compile and test. Please post instructions on how to create a minimal project that recreates your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot @roccobaroccoSC  -  EnumChildWindow API did the trick for me - thanks a ton for your valid input